# Suave project with Ionide

Tags: .net, visual-studio-code, f#, suave, ionide

I'm trying to create a Suave project via Ionide, but it only gives me these options: classlib, console, saturn, expecto. What should I do to Suave appears to me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suave has not been integrated into the VSCode command pallette, so you could create a new project from the command line instead.

Run this from the command line to add the Suave project template to the dotnet new command:

```
dotnet new -i Suave.Template
```

Now create an empty folder for your project, and open or cd a cmd line to that folder.

Then run this from the command line to create a new project:

```
dotnet new Suave --name suave-project --language F#
```

See more instructions at https://github.com/JacobChang/Suave.Template#using-the-template

Comment: It's worth noting that work has begun in ionide to integrate the new-project command with the `dotnet cli` template system here, so eventually the projects you can create will be the same across both systems!